# How to proof the convolution product with the Fourier integral?

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, residue-calculus, fast-fourier-transform

One should prove the following:

$\mathcal{F}_k^{-1}[\tilde f (k)\tilde g (k)](x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(f * g)(x)$

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this exercise. I researched for articles and websites regarding this topic, but couldn't find anything similar :( I would be very thankful for any help!

Comment: Have you tried to take the Fourier transform of the right hand side, expanding the convolution and rewritten the double integral into two nonconnected integrals?

Comment: I indeed tried to do so, but failed terribly. I got $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int (\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}f(x)e^{-ikx}dxe^{ikx}\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}g(x)e^{-ikx}dxe^{ikx})dx$ this seems to be terrible wrong and of course the terms containing $e^{ikx}$'s cancel out

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\int (f*g)(x) \, e^{-ix\xi} \, dx
&= \int \left( \int f(x-y)\,g(y)\,dy \right) \, e^{-ix\xi} \, dx
\\
&= \iint f(x-y)\,g(y)\,e^{-ix\xi}\,dy\,dx
\\
&= \int \left( \int f(x-y) \, e^{-ix\xi} \, dx \right) g(y) \, dy
\\
&\stackrel{z:=x-y}{=} \int \left( \int f(z) \, e^{-i(y+z)\xi} \, dz \right) g(y) \, dy
\\
&= \int \left( \int f(z) \, e^{-iz\xi} \, dz \right) g(y) e^{-iy\xi} \, dy
\\
&= \left( \int f(z) \, e^{-iz\xi} \, dz \right) \left( \int  g(y) e^{-iy\xi} \, dy \right)\end{align}
$$